# Deserialize objects in Flutter from json using map didn't work

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter. I was trying deserialize json string and make dart objects. But I can't.

When I try to map, it won't execute debugPrint(). I don't know why and there is no erorr? please help me.
API is working fine. When I print data using response.body - it also prints the real json data.

```
  Future<List<User>> fetchData() async {
    List<User> users;

    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.http(' 192.168.0.102:8000', 'api/users'),
    );
    print(response.statusCode);
    //print(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final list = json.decode(response.body) as List;
      print('is $list');

      // for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      users = list.map((e) {
        debugPrint(e);
        return User(id: e['id'], bap: e['bap'], lgNumber: e['lgnumber']);
      });
      // }
      print('after');
      return users;
    
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
              snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                User user = snapshot.data[index];
                return Text(
                  user.bap.toString(),
                );
              },
            );
          }
          return Container();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I am not using the same data type in both Flutter and Laravel. I used int in Flutter and string in Laravel or backend. But there was no errors that made the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use this for fetch List of User from json

```
 users = list.map((e) {
    //debugPrint(e.toString());
    return User(id: e['id'], bap: e['bap'], lgNumber: e['lgnumber']);
  }).toList();
```